# Mounting NFS server through SSH reverse tunnel

Tags: ssh, nfs, mount, ssh-tunnel

Here is my setup:

- Office computer in a network, with no way to access from outside, (OC)
- embedded computer in the field (FC)
- Server in the office, containing data to which the field computer needs access. Office computer mounts a directory from this server, it is NFS

I regularly work on the field computer over SSH, the problem is to access the data on the office server from the field computer.

So far I have solved this by mounting the field computer in my office computer with `sshfs`. It works ok but it has drawbacks. I would like to get and push info directly from my SSH session, not from another local session on my local office computer (for example, running `git` from the sshfs mountpoint is very slow).

I understand that this could be achieved by an SSH reverse tunnel.

Here is what I have tried, logging in from office computer (OC) to field computer (FC):

```
gauthier@OC $ ssh -R 9001:<nfs_server_name>:2049 FC
```

(FC is setup in my `~/.ssh/config`)

As far as I understand, this opens port 9001 on FC, to listen to OC's idea of `<nfs_server_name>` on port 2049.

9001 could be anything that is not reserved, 2049 is the port for NFS.

I can ping `<nfs_server_name>` from OC.

After `SSH` to FC, I try to mount the port as NFS:

```
gauthier@FC $ mkdir mp_test
gauthier@FC $ sudo mount -t nfs localhost:9001 mp_test/
```

This just hangs, then times out.

I thought I might need to give a path in the NFS server, so I also tried:

```
gauthier@FC $ sudo mount -t nfs localhost:9001:/path/to/directory/I/usually/mount mp_test/
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong, either with ports or with `mount`.

What has been working is to make FC's port 9001 to listen to OC's `<nfs_server_name>` on port 80. Then I could open `localhost:9001` on FC and see the NFS server's web interface. This makes me think I'm quite close.

How do I mount the office NFS server directory on the field computer?

---

After [some more search](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/nfs-mount-through-reversed-ssh-tunnel-944099/), I tried this:

```
gauthier@OC $ ssh -R 5100:<server>:2049 -R 5200:<server>:2233 FC
gauthier@FC $ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o port=5100,mountport=5200 localhost:/path/to/share/dir mp_test
[sudo] password for gauthier: 
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr 30 14:14:27 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'port=5100,mountport=5200,vers=4,addr=127.0.0.1,clientaddr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'port=5100,mountport=5200,addr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

And with `tcp` (at this point you can see I am trying black magic formulas without understanding what I am doing :/):

```
gauthier@FC $ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o tcp,port=5100,mountport=5200 localhost:/path/to/share/dir mp_test/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr 30 14:15:04 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'tcp,port=5100,mountport=5200,vers=4,addr=127.0.0.1,clientaddr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'tcp,port=5100,mountport=5200,addr=127.0.0.1'
connect_to <server> port 2233: failed.
connect_to <server> port 2233: failed.
connect_to <server> port 2233: failed.
```

Comment: If sshfs is slow, NFS is going to be no better, even if you *can* get it working through the tunnel.

Comment: I think sshfs is slow with `git` because I run OC's `git` from a repo that is on `sshfs`. My hope is that running `git` from FC's local repo would be faster, since it is designed to work that way with `push` and `pull` (push and get changes from remote to local, not the opposite as working from within `sshfs` is)

Comment: But I'd be ok with mounting the server on FC with sshfs, I guess. As in, ssh to FC, setup a sshfs back from FC to server. In that case, the sshfs directory would be `git`'s remote, not `git`'s local, which is what I want. I've tried that, to no av ("read: Connection reset by peer").

Comment: It's not only the speed, it's also more practical to `git push` and `pull` from the ssh session.